# Grafana/PromQL group values for max_over_time

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, promql

I want to have the current, the min and the max value for the replica status in a table in grafana for each service. I am using kube_deployment_status_replicas{deployment=~"$deployment"} and the max_over_time(kube_deployment_status_replicas{deployment=~"$deployment"}[30m]). But the problem with the max_over_time is that I am not getting just one value, but several values for each deployment/service. I just want one value for every service like this:
time | metric | pod | min[30m] | max[30m]
now  | ms     | 5   | 2        | 7
[image]
When I change the time range to be shown it gives me serveral values for each service, but even when i make the time just to now, it gives me more than one value just making the time steps to milliseconds.

Comment: is this problem only for max_over_time? maybe you have metric for different cluster/namespace/instance? Maybe you could upload some visualisation?

Comment: Can you provide further information like yaml code and other steps for reproducing the issue? Have you verified the metrics by passing only one deployment and have you checked whether you have provided a unique naming convention for the pods.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the yaml code, but I have checked that the pods have unique names and that I am only passing one deployment. I noticed that it has nothing to do with max_over_time function, but for kube_deployment_status_replicas{deployment=~"$deployment"}
in general I get a value for each deployment every 30 seconds. I still get the multiple values, but with just sorting it by time, I am seeing just latest ones, which is what I want. The other values are still there, but its fine. Thanks!